# how to correctly get django models from db using jquery?

Tags: json, django-models, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get the models from django but nothing is showing up. The app is deployed on Google App Engine.

This is the errors I see:

```
AttributeError at /get_companies_json

'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_companies_json
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Below are my urls, view functions:

URL:

```
('^get_companies_json$', 'companies.views.all_companies_json')
```

views function:

```
def all_companies_json(request):
    # json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")();
    companies_json = serializers.serialize("json", Company.objects.filter(approved = True));
    return companies_json;
```

jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("/get_companies_json",
            function(data){
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
                    console.log(item);
                });             
            }
        );
```

I am following the example on jQuery site: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this function

```
def all_companies_json(request):
    # json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")();
    companies_json = serializers.serialize("json", Company.objects.filter(approved = True));
    return companies_json;
```

Needs to be changed to

```
def all_companies_json(request):
    # json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")();
    companies_json = serializers.serialize("json", Company.objects.filter(approved = True));
    return HttpResponse(companies_json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone at some point. If i remember right the mimetype part can be of particular importance sometimes when dealing with json responses.